# Finding cell state in OpenNMT-py

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, opennmt

I can't seem to find a value for the cell state when loading a model trained with a network of LSTM neurons in OpenNMT-py. I can only find the weight matrices and biases under 'model' in the model loaded with torch.load. Does anyone know if the cell state is saved for the model and if so, where?

Comment: Could you please explain more which cell state do you mean?

Comment: The number stored in the cell state of the LSTM, as opposed to the hidden state.